# Print winform in C#

Tags: c#

How to print a whole winform in c# 2008.?

My form contains picturebox, 3 text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PrintForm control in the Visual Basic PowerPack. It is available from the ToolBox in VS 2008 even in C# projects. I think it may have been added in SP1. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb735936.aspx).

Comment: Yes its available, How to use it?

Comment: Can you at least try to look into it before asking questions?

Answer (score 0):

Thought it is possible to do without a 3rd party library, I have used [PrintForm.Net](http://www.winformreports.co.uk/features_pf.htm) in the past with success.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing;

private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   printForm1.Print(this, PrintForm.PrintOption.ClientAreaOnly);
}
```

For PrintOptions See this link in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.printform.printoption(VS.80).aspx)