# c# runtime reports design

Tags: c#, .net, report

How do I runtime reports design with C#
winform

http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Pro/HX_Adding_Runtime_Designer_to_your_Project.html
I want to do this kind of program. After modified by myself I will, I will include their own slots. How do I make such checks.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896074/c-winforms-print-entire-form, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424924/print-winform-in-c

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/srajlaxmi/PrintingWindowsForm01182008021239AM/PrintingWindowsForm.aspx) is a little old, but should still hopefully do the trick for regular WinForms.  If you go with WPF or something in the future then it may no longer apply.

Comment: That article would certainly work, but I notice that it's importing `BitBlt` to copy the form from the screen, which is now included in the Framework as the `CopyFromScreen` method. Here's a more updated sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx

Comment: I'm looking for it does not, it prints the form. run-time I want, print the form design

Comment: @user520411: I don't understand what you are trying to say. How is the form "design" different from printing the form itself? Do you have a picture box or other specific control on the form that you want to print?

Comment: pardon me I mean exactly the runtime report design

Comment: @user520411: I think you're going to need to be more specific in that case.  Consider thoroughly revising the question (more so than you already have).  What kind of tools/controls are you currently using for reporting?  What exactly are you trying to do?  (Modify at runtime isn't particularly clear.)  Are you trying to fill in fields in the report, change design elements, etc.?  This still goes back to a heavy dependency on the report tool(s) you're using.

Comment: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Pro/HX_Adding_Runtime_Designer_to_your_Project.html I want to do something exactly like this. but I am going to modify the slots will hold its own data.