# Printing a hidden Form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

i have a windows form that contains a bunch of textboxes. I need a way to print them out on a peice of paper. What i did is transfer the information from the first form to the second form. I formated the second form the way i wanted it to look like when i printed it. I am using the PrintForm Control. Using this controls makes me have to make it visible to print it.

Is there any other way i can print my second form right when it loads and hide it so that the user does not see that form?

Comment: Duplicating the form is going cause you headaches in maintaining your code. (Unless this is a small project). Although its more work, I would suggest cycling through the controls in your original form along with their positions and creating a pdf representation of the form.

Comment: Ok, how would i do that...also, are there third party free applications that can help me print?

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424924/print-winform-in-c-sharp in particula Brians answer in regards to PrintForm.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the form visible, but just out of view. E.g `Location = new Point(-1000, -1000);`